# Extracting Machine Specifications from Google Cloud from an SKU

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am trying to extract price information about the virtual machines supplied by the compute engine service in Google Cloud. I have successfully extracted a JSON file with some pricing information on it using an HTTP Get request from Google Cloud's Pricing API, however all of the pricing data in the file is mapped to individual machines via the SKU number, and there are no machine specifications associated with any of the SKU numbers. Here is the request:

GET https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com/v1/services?key=API_KEY

Ideally, I would like to find a way to have the machine specifications included in the JSON file returned by the HTTP request, but if that isn't possible I'd like to find a way use the SKU to look up a machine's specifications. For example, if my SKU is: 19E4-D27B-7C12, I'd like to use that code to look up the machine it specifies and see details about it such as amount of RAM, number of CPUs, etc... Does anyone know of any Google Cloud resources that would allow me to do such a thing? And if not, is there any other way to accomplish this task? I'd like this process to be programmatic so I cannot use the built in calculator in Google Cloud.

Thank you!

Comment: I am having exactly the same question above, was you able to find any information that from SKU , how to get machine specifications like RAM , number of CPUs etc. Many thanks

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you found a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like currently there is no an API that can get the features of a certain machine type, however, there is an API:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/get

That allows you to get detailed features of an existing virtual machine based on the project, the zone and the instance name.